# Getting info from a random previously submitted php form, after submitting the same php form

Tags: php, forms, email

I think im kind of a noob here, so im sorry if the question sounds stupid...

I need to create a php form with different fields (eg. name, email, city, etc.), which(the form) after submitting will result in showing the random name, email, city, etc. info with "YES" or "NO" buttons, and if the answer is no, it gets another random info.

The trick is that the info shown after submitting has to be the info, that another person has previously submitted using the first form.

Also, after clicking "YES" the info has to be sent to the e-mail, which was submitted in the first form.

Tried to search for something similar, no result.

Any help is appreciated, if you know a good solution, i am waiting for you reply!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a lot. Show some effort so we can help you instead of making it for you.

You need to try and make the following using tutorials etc before proceeding.

```
1) Save the info in a file, maybe more then one or a database when a user submits.
2) Get a saved form at random when a user navigates to the form
3) Put info into form
4) Send email
```